# Join on "max value that is less than..." without first having to join to everything less than

Tags: mysql

This seems like it should be a very basic question, and there are plenty of *somewhat* similar questions around, but after many hours of research and trial and error, I cannot find an answer. My apologies if this is repetitive.

I want to join to a table based on two conditions:

column_1 = something_1 AND
column_2 = max(all the possible entries less than something_2).

I think I should be able to do this:

```
Select t1.id, t2.id from table1 as t1
join
(select t1.id, max(t2.condition_2) as big_condition_2 from table1 as t1
join table2 as t2
on t2.condition_1 = t1.condition_1 and t2.condition_2 < t1.condition_2
group by t1.id) as t3
on t3.id = t1.id
join table2 t2
on t2.condition_1 = t1.condition_1 and t2.condition_2 = t3.big_condition_2
```

This query is currently timing out after 20 minutes and I have no idea how long it would take should I remove the timeout. I'm pretty sure its something I'm doing wrong.

Each table has on average around 100 types of `condition_1` and then each condition has approximately 4000 different `condition_2` values. So each table has between 300k - 500k rows. I estimate then that the subquery should generate approximately 2000 x 100 = 200k joins - wasteful, but I wouldn't think that should cause such a long delay. Note that `condition_1` is an `int` and `condition_2` is a `varchar(21)`.

I have indexes on each of the referenced fields, either individually or multiple where necessary, however perhaps the fact that I've generated this t3 table is slowing things down massively because the join to t3 doesn't use an index?

I think more fundamentally though, what I want to know is if there is a way I can choose the particular value to join to without doing all these otherwise unnecessary joins? That is, do something like (pseudocode):

```
select t1.id, t2.id from table1 as t1
join table2 as t2
on t2.condition_1 = t1.condition_1
and t2.condition_2 = max(t2.condition_2 where t2.condition_2 > t1.condition_1)
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

**UPDATE**

On Steve's request I tried to run an explain on the query but it too timed out after 20 minutes. I then tried to run an explain on just the subquery portion and got the following output

**UPDATE 2** I added some new indexes and re-ran explain on the subquery. Here are the results (formatted so they're more readable now too):

```
id  select_type  table  type    possible_keys                           key                  key_len  ref                       rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE       esnap  index   ticker_id,ticker_id_2,date_time_GMT     PRIMARY              4        null                      20  
1   SIMPLE       ep     ref     primary_ticker_id,secondary_ticker_id   secondary_ticker_id  5        adr.esnap.ticker_id       1       Using where
1   SIMPLE       ets    ref     ticker_id,date_time_GMT                 ticker_id            5        adr.ep.primary_ticker_id  22430   Using where; Using index
```

As way of explanation, `esnap` is `tableA`, `ets` is `tableB` and `ep` is a table which is an intermediate table that is required to join tableA to tableB. So the subquery is actually:

```
select esnap.security_snap_id, max(ets.date_time_GMT) as snap_time from
equity_snapshots esnap
join equity_pairs ep on ep.secondary_ticker_id = esnap.ticker_id
join equity_trade_snaps ets on ets.ticker_id = ep.primary_ticker_id and
ets.date_time_GMT < esnap.date_time_GMT
group by esnap.security_snap_id
```

where the `ticker_id` is an `int` and the `date_time_GMT` is a `varchar(21)`.

**ASKING THE IMPOSSIBLE?**

On further consideration, I think the subquery generates a table that is just too big. There are roughly 100 pairs to match (`condition_1`), each pair has around 6500 distinct ids in tableA and 3500 distinct ids in tableB. This means that there will be roughly 100 * 6500 * (3500/2) = 1.1 billion rows joined *prior* to grouping.

**Resorting to Java...**

Unless someone else can suggest a way that avoids the subquery (i.e. joins only to the "max less than", rather than "ALL less than, then group") I think I'm going to give up and use java to import the whole table, do its thing, then output the results back to mySql. This all seems very time consuming for something that should be a lot simpler.... so if anyone has a better solution please let me know.

Comment: Can you provide an EXPLAIN output of the query

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t3.id, t2.id from (select t1.id,t1.condition_1, max(t2.condition_2) as big_condition_2 from table1 as t1
JOIN table2 as t2
on t2.condition_1 = t1.condition_1 and t2.condition_2 < t2.condition_2
group by t1.id,t1.condition_1 ) as t3

JOIN table2 t2
on t2.condition_1 = t3.condition_1 and t2.condition_2 = t3.big_condition_2
```

Need change condition `t2.condition_2 < t2.condition_2` as always false might be typo.

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed the question now. As per my update this wasn't the actual query though, so this wasn't the cause of the problem.

Comment: I have tried to run it with your modifications, but it still times out. Each `id` is unique, so `group by t1.id, t1.condition_1` will yield the same result as `group by t1.id`, though removing the `t1.condition_1` from the group statement doesn't help either unfortunately.